# alignment is getting messed up in the menu header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on menu header but somehow all my elements are not getting aligned in one horizontal line. They are getting shown just below each other. Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2nv4dd2w/29/)

Below is my HTML:

```
<div class="topnav">
    <img src="https://s4.postimg.org/ojd13poal/northman_wordmark_CMYK.png">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#"><b>INSURANCE</b> <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-content">
                    <li><a href="#"><i>INDIVIDUAL</i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i>CORPORATE</i></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="our-story">OUR STORY</li>
            <li class="login-signup">Log In | Sign up</li>
            <li class="get-covered">GET <strong style="font-style:italic">COVERED</strong>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: AvantGarde Demi;
    src: url(AvantGarde Demi.woff);
}
@font-face {
    font-family: AvantGarde;
    src: url(AvantGarde.woff);
}
@font-face {
    font-family: ITC Avant Garde Gothic;
    src: url(ITC Avant Garde Gothic.woff);
}
.topnav {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.topnav > img,
nav {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
nav > ul {
    margin: 0;
}
.topnav .dropdown {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
.topnav a {
    color: white;
    display: block;
    font-size: 17px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.topnav .dropdown > a {
    padding: 20px 16px;
}
.topnav .dropdown-content li > a {
    padding: 10px 16px;
}
.topnav ul > li > ul {
    background-color: #f76c38;
    display: none;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
}
.topnav ul > li > ul > li {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}
body {
    border: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.fa-6 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
.login {
    color: white;
    display: inline;
    font-family: AvantGarde;
    font-size: 11.433px;
    letter-spacing: .25em;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
.login a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.login a:hover {
    color: #fe5b1f;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.container {
    width: 100% !important;
}
li.insurance {
    padding-top: 30px !important;
}
li.our-story {
    padding-top: 30px !important;
}
li.login-signup {
    padding-top: 30px !important;
}
li.get-covered {
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 10px !important;
    padding-top: 10px !important;
}
li.our-story {
    color: white;
    font-family: AvantGarde;
    letter-spacing: .30em;
}
li.login-signup {
    color: white;
    font-family: Adelle PE;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: italic;
    letter-spacing: .30em;
}
li.get-covered {
    border-color: #EF7440;
    border-style: solid;
    color: white;
    font-family: Adelle PE;
    letter-spacing: .30em;
}
li.get-covered:hover {
    background-color: #EF7440;
}
li.insurance {
    color: white;
    font-family: AvantGarde;
    letter-spacing: .30em;
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-right: 80px;
}
```

I want everything to be aligned horizontally in one line in the menu header. As an example look at this [image](https://s1.postimg.org/pqi3delvj/head.png), it is slightly tilted but you will get an idea how my menu header looks on that black background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your CSS:

```
nav > ul > li {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: yup got it now why it was getting messed up. Here is my updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2nv4dd2w/30/) but it is still not fully aligned as you can see in my fiddle if you compare with the image I provided in the question. Any thoughts why?

Comment: I cleaned up your CSS, changing code into comment using /* ... */. Please see the fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/beekvang/2nv4dd2w/31/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:flex`.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: AvantGarde Demi;
    src: url(AvantGarde Demi.woff);
}
@font-face {
    font-family: AvantGarde;
    src: url(AvantGarde.woff);
}
@font-face {
    font-family: ITC Avant Garde Gothic;
    src: url(ITC Avant Garde Gothic.woff);
}
.topnav {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 10px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.topnav > img,
nav {
    display: block;
}
nav > ul {
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.topnav .dropdown {
}
.topnav a {
    color: white;
    display: block;
    font-size: 17px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.topnav .dropdown > a {
    padding: 20px 16px;
}
.topnav .dropdown-content li > a {
    padding: 10px 16px;
}
.topnav ul > li > ul {
    background-color: #f76c38;
    display: none;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
}
.topnav ul > li > ul > li {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}
body {
    border: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.fa-6 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
.login {
    color: white;
    display: inline;
    font-family: AvantGarde;
    font-size: 11.433px;
    letter-spacing: .25em;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
.login a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.login a:hover {
    color: #fe5b1f;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.container {
    width: 100% !important;
}

li.get-covered {
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 10px !important;
    padding-top: 10px !important;
}
li.our-story {
    color: white;
    font-family: AvantGarde;
    letter-spacing: .30em;
}
li.login-signup {
    color: white;
    font-family: Adelle PE;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: italic;
    letter-spacing: .30em;
}
li.get-covered {
    border-color: #EF7440;
    border-style: solid;
    color: white;
    font-family: Adelle PE;
    letter-spacing: .30em;
}
li.get-covered:hover {
    background-color: #EF7440;
}
li.insurance {
    color: white;
    font-family: AvantGarde;
    letter-spacing: .30em;
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-right: 80px;
}
```